# Arc length of $\sin^3({\frac x3})$ from $0$ to $6\pi$

Tags: definite-integrals

> How can I find the arc length for $P(x) = \sin^3\left({\frac x3}\right)$ from $0$ to $6\pi$.

I try to find:

$$\int_0^{6\pi} \sqrt{1 + \cos^2\left({\frac x3}\right)\sin^4\left({\frac x3}\right)}\,\mathrm dx$$

but I can't. Help me please, or just show me the way to solve it.

Maybe it could be done in polar coordinates?

Comment: Maple cannot do that integral as an antiderivative. maybe with the specific bounds it can be done.

Comment: Have you tried using standard substitution?